# Design for old browser, backwards compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to sync my design for old browsers IE7 and up. Here is my design for old browsers IE7 and up, I have searched and found a tool to download and use Javascript to implement the code. Is there another way to do this?

Here is my Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>

    <title>Nitro Data Networks Teleserv Corporation</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://nitrodatanetworks.com/assets/main.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://nitrodatanetworks.com/assets/contact.css"/>
     <script src="http://nitrodatanetworks.com/assets/modernize.js.css"/>" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>


    <body>
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', '--snip--', '--snip--');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script><div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <ul>
            <a href="http://nitrodatanetworks.com/index.php">   <li>
          <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/65-32.png">Home</a></li>
               <a href="http://nitrodatanetworks.com/index.php/welcome/login">   <li><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/91-32.png">Login</a></li>
             <a href="http://nitrodatanetworks.com/index.php/welcome/profile">  <li><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/88-32.png"> Profile</li>
             <a href="http://nitrodatanetworks.com/index.php/welcome/service">    <li><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/16-32.png">Services</li>
          <a href="http://nitrodatanetworks.com/index.php/welcome/contact"> <li><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/04-32.png">Contact us</a></li>
            <div id="social">
            <li>Like Us!<img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social_balloons/48px/social_balloon-14.png"></li>
             <li>Tweet!<img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social_balloons/48px/social_balloon-05.png"></li>
              <li>Plus!<img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social_balloons/48px/social_balloon-19.png"></li>

              </div>


        </ul>
    </div>


    <!---------------------------header------------------->  <!---------------slideshow--------------------->
    <ul class="slides">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRphs0UnDqpha8RwnVqAXzwB9p1Z8in352q4bjo1pPFmMffniIA6g" />
                <p class="text">Nitro Data Networks Teleserv Corporation</p>
              <p class="subtext">We are focus on aligning IT services with the needs of our client's business.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRphs0UnDqpha8RwnVqAXzwB9p1Z8in352q4bjo1pPFmMffniIA6g" />
                <p class="text">Flexibility</p>
                <p class="subtext">VoIP systems allow end-users to carry their phone number everywhere on the planet,
as long as the location has internet access. This is significantly beneficial to 
companies, organizations, and agencies that conduct business domestically and 
internationally.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRphs0UnDqpha8RwnVqAXzwB9p1Z8in352q4bjo1pPFmMffniIA6g" />
                <p class="text">Cost Savings</p>
                <p class="subtext">Leveraging VoIP to make international calls can translate into huge savings for end-
users over traditional phone lines. Most VoIP providers offer their consumers 
excellent rates when making calls internationally.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>   
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRphs0UnDqpha8RwnVqAXzwB9p1Z8in352q4bjo1pPFmMffniIA6g" />
                <p class="text">Nitro Data Networks Teleserv Corporation</p>
                <p class="subtext">We are focus on aligning IT services with the needs of our client's business.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRphs0UnDqpha8RwnVqAXzwB9p1Z8in352q4bjo1pPFmMffniIA6g" />
                 <p class="text">Application Integration</p>
  <p class="subtext">VoIP solutions save the end-user time and money by integrating web applications,
email, audio, and data with telephone requirements into one easy-to-use application.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
        <li class="slide-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRphs0UnDqpha8RwnVqAXzwB9p1Z8in352q4bjo1pPFmMffniIA6g" />
                <p class="text">Nitro Data Networks Teleserv Corporation </p>
                <p class="subtext"> Nitro Data's Core team has played a leading role across a broad range of industry activities, built successful businesses and created sustainable long-term relationships with our partners.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
                <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-dots">
            <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
            <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
            <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
            <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
            <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
            <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!------------------------------------>    <div id="nav-post">
         <h2>Coming soon</h2>

        <p> Nitro Data Networks Teleserv Corporation (Nitro Data) is one of the trusted technological solutions provider for many computer-telecommunication. Nitro Data has served to assist many organizations in using their computer-telecommunications assets more efficiently and effectively. Our services are all inline with the internationally accredited set of practices for IT service management. 
</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="services">
    <h2>VOIP Benefits</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="img-1" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/19-64.png">
                    <a href="http://nitrodatanetworks.com/index.php/welcome/login">  <h1>Application Integration</h1></a>

                    <p>VoIP solutions save the end-user time and money by integrating web applications, email, audio, and data with telephone requirements into one easy-to-use application.</p>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="img-2" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/21-64.png">
                   <a href="http://nitrodatanetworks.com/index.php/welcome/flexibity">     <h1>Flexibility</h1></a>

                    <p>VoIP systems allow end-users to carry their phone number everywhere on the planet, as long as the location has internet access.This is significantly beneficial to companies.
</p>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="img-3" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <img src=https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pittogrammi/142/94-64.png>
                 <a href="http://nitrodatanetworks.com/index.php/welcome/costsavings">         <h1>Cost Savings</h1></a>

                    <p>Leveraging VoIP to make international calls can translate into huge savings for end- users over traditional phone lines.Most VoIP providers offer their consumers excellent rates.</p>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><div id="footer">
<h2>Nitro Data Networks Teleserv</h2>
<div id="footercontent">

<ul class="footer1">
<li>Careers</li>
<li>Contac Us</li>
<li>Locations</li>

</ul>

<ul class="footer2">
<li>Our Team</li>
<li>Where we started</li>
<li>Information</li>

</ul>

<ul class="footer3">
<li>Sitemap</li>
<li>Location Map</li>
<li>Privacy Policy</li>

</ul>


</div><!-----footer content------------------------>

</div><!-----footer------------------------------->
<div id='footercopy'>
<p>Terms of use</p>
<p>&copy 2014 Netsolutions Technologies</p>
</div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Here is the Css:

```
  /*Developed and designed by Chris Einar M. San Agustin*/

  html{
        background:background: background: #4c4c4c; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4c4c4c 0%, #000000 0%, #000000 0%, #595959 12%, #666666 25%, #474747 39%, #2c2c2c 50%, #111111 60%, #2b2b2b 76%, #1c1c1c 91%, #131313 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4c4c4c), color-stop(0%,#000000), color-stop(0%,#000000), color-stop(12%,#595959), color-stop(25%,#666666), color-stop(39%,#474747), color-stop(50%,#2c2c2c), color-stop(60%,#111111), color-stop(76%,#2b2b2b), color-stop(91%,#1c1c1c), color-stop(100%,#131313)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #4c4c4c 0%,#000000 0%,#000000 0%,#595959 12%,#666666 25%,#474747 39%,#2c2c2c 50%,#111111 60%,#2b2b2b 76%,#1c1c1c 91%,#131313 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #4c4c4c 0%,#000000 0%,#000000 0%,#595959 12%,#666666 25%,#474747 39%,#2c2c2c 50%,#111111 60%,#2b2b2b 76%,#1c1c1c 91%,#131313 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #4c4c4c 0%,#000000 0%,#000000 0%,#595959 12%,#666666 25%,#474747 39%,#2c2c2c 50%,#111111 60%,#2b2b2b 76%,#1c1c1c 91%,#131313 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #4c4c4c 0%,#000000 0%,#000000 0%,#595959 12%,#666666 25%,#474747 39%,#2c2c2c 50%,#111111 60%,#2b2b2b 76%,#1c1c1c 91%,#131313 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4c4c4c', endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;

        }

        h2{
        font-size:50px;
        font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;

        }

        #wrapper{
        width:1024px;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
        min-height:1000px;

        }

        #header{
         width:1024px;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
        position:relative;
        left:-20px;
        color:#000000;
        padding-top:50px;
        padding-bottom:10px;

        }

        #header li{
        display:inline;
        padding:20px;
        background:#FFF;
        opacity:0.5;

        }
        #header img{

        }
        #social{
           text-align:right;

          }
        #social li{
          background:#C8C8C8 ;
         position:relative;
         top:-53px;
         padding-left:10px;

          }
        #header li:hover{


          opacity:1;




          }
          #header a{
          text-decoration:none;
          color:#000000;
          }




        /*slideshow*/
          /*slider*/
          @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);



          .slides {
          width:1024px;
          padding-right:65px;
          height:420px;
          display: block;
          position: relative;
          z-index:11;
          }

          .slides * {
              user-select: none;
              -ms-user-select: none;
              -moz-user-select: none;
              -khtml-user-select: none;
              -webkit-user-select: none;
              -webkit-touch-callout: none;
          }

          .slides input { display: none; }

          .slide-container { display: block; }

          .text{
           background-color: rgba(0, 0, 5, 0.3);
background: rgba(0, 0, 5, 0.3);
color: rgba(0, 0, 5, 0.3);
           text-align:center;
           opacity:0.8;
           font-size:50px;
           width:800px;
           color:white;
           position:relative;
           left:100px;
           margin-top:-400px;
          }
          .subtext
          {
                     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 5, 0.5);
background: rgba(0, 0, 5, 0.3);
color: rgba(0, 0, 5, 0.3);
padding:20px;
           color:white; 
           font-size:15px;
           position:relative;
           font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
           text-align:left;
           left:100px;
           right:110px;
           width:500px;

          }
          .slide
          {
          top: 0;
          left:-11px;
          opacity: 0;
          margin-left:auto;
          margin-right:auto;
          width:100%;
          height:100%;
          text-align:center;
              display: block;
              position: absolute;

              transform: scale(0);
              -moz-transform: scale(0);
              -webkit-transform: scale(0);

              transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
              -moz-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
              -webkit-transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
          }

          .slide img {
          margin-right:auto;
          width:1024px;
          margin-left:-83px;
          margin-top:-10px;
          height:110%;
          text-align:center;

          }

          .nav label {
              width: 200px;
              height:0%;
              display:none;
              position: absolute;
              margin-left:-35px;
              margin-right:110px;
              padding:auto;

              opacity: 0;
              z-index: 9;
              cursor: pointer;

              transition: opacity .2s;
              -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
              -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;

              color: #FFF;
                font-size: 150px;
              text-align: center;
              line-height: 380px;
              font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
              background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
              text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
          }

          .slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

          .nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

          .nav .next { right: 0; }


          input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
              opacity: 1;

              transform: scale(1);
              -moz-transform: scale(1);
              -webkit-transform: scale(1);

              transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
              -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
              -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
          }

          input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

          .nav-dots {
              width: 960px;
              bottom: 0px;
            height: 1px;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            text-align:center;
          }

          .nav-dots .nav-dot {
            top: -5px;
            width: 11px;
            height: 11px;

            position: relative;
            border-radius: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
          }

          .nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
          }

          input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
          input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
          input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
          input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
          input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
          input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
          }
          #nav-post{
            padding-top:30px;
            color:#FFF;
              padding:20px;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;


            }
          #nav-post h2{
           text-align:center;



          }




          #services{
             padding-top:50px;
             padding-bottom:40px;
            color:#FCFCFC;

            }
             #services h2{
             text-align:center;

             }

          #services li{
          display:inline-block;
        padding:30px;
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;

          }  

          #services li:hover{
          font-weight:bold;
          font-size:20px;

          }
          #services img{
            background:#FFF;
            border-radius:70px;
            padding:30px;
            opacity:0.5;



            }
            #services p{
              width:200PX;  
        text-align:left;
              color:#FFF;
               font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;



              }
            #services h1{
             padding-top:20px;
              color:#888888;
              text-align:left;

              }
              #services img:hover{
                position:relative;
                top:-20px;
                opacity:1;

                }
                #services a{
                text-decoration:none;

                }


#footer
{
 clear:both;
background: rgb(96,108,136); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(96,108,136,1) 0%, rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(96,108,136,1)), color-stop(0%,rgba(63,76,107,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(96,108,136,1) 0%,rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(96,108,136,1) 0%,rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(96,108,136,1) 0%,rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(96,108,136,1) 0%,rgba(63,76,107,1) 0%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#606c88', endColorstr='#3f4c6b',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


 margin-top:-23px;
 min-height:300px;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-left:auto;
 text-align:center;
 overflow:hidden;
 font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
 color:#FFFFFF;
}
#footer h2:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}

#footercontent
{
width:1024px;
font-weight:20px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}
#footer h2{
text-decoration:none;
}
.footer1 
{
float:left;
padding-left:100px;
padding-right:150px;

}
.footer2 
{
float:left;
padding-right:150px;
}
.footer3 
{
float:left;
padding-right:150px;
}
.footer4 
{
float:left;
padding-right:100px;
}
.footer5
{
float:left;
padding-right:100px;
}

#footercopy
{
background:#404040;
text-align:center;
padding:20px;
margin-bottom:-10px;
color:white;
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. It's not clear what you're asking. It's not clear what you're asking. It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: You define "old browsers" as IE7 and newer?

Comment: Why do you want to support IE7?  Just because you feel like it, or do you have a compelling reason to do so?  If you want to use any amount of CSS3 functionality, you will find trying to make some backwards compatible equivalent to be an exercise in pain. that being said, what is the actual question?  Is there another way to do what?

Comment: Is there a script where I can embed on the code that could make the Html5 code compatible with old browsers

Comment: The client wants a wider reach so he wants all browsers to be working

Comment: As you can see if you use IE7 the code code doesn't work well.

Comment: Ask the client which is more important HTML5/CSS3 or reaching antiquated browser probably only still used in China?  Tell theem it is going to cost a lot more money for something that probably brings little value. At some point, you have to narrow your focus here or your client will spend time developing IE7 compatibility that should be spent actually adding more features or whatever.  Unless you have a website with HUGE amounts of traffic such that not supporting IE7 means a big hit to bottom line, chances are you should not mess with it.

Comment: @Qix Thanks for the edit; failed to catch that.

Comment: ALright then, so there's no other way?@Mr. Brant

Comment: @ChrisEinarSanAgustin What you would probably want to do is auto-detect browser and serve up different HTML.  But then you are maintaining two different things - a big pain.

Comment: @ChrisEinarSanAgustin Why do you *need* to support IE7? It's archaic and even IE8 doesn't play well with many modern designs.

Comment: @Mr. Brant,Yes exactly, when I looked at CMS-based templates particularly wordpress it works on IE7 but not that good compared to webkit browsers, but when I checked my code on IE7 it doesn't look good compared to the CMS-based templates.

Comment: @Qix I am building my portfolio, I know you guys are experts on this field, I am just learning to see how to get this done script-wise(Javascript) or Jquery script.

Comment: As far as CSS goes, I suppose you could rewrite it using bootstrap 2, which was still IE7 compatible: http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.2/docs/ There's a whole heap of javascript that doesn't work in IE7/8 either. It'll be a pain.

Comment: And we're telling you it's not possible. To polyfill everything new browsers provide HTML5-wise to a browser that old is impossible for various reasons, most of them being security reasons. You *will never* be able to polyfill the location, websocket, history, audio, etc. APIs in an efficient way. You'll have to replace and re-create tags dynamically, meaning *extremely* slow load times. Plus, [**nobody uses IE7 seriously anymore**](http://briteweb.com/internet-browser-usage-ie-7/). Seriously.

Comment: @Qix ALright, i'll educate the client.

Comment: It's not hard to write a feature rich site using code that works in older browsers so long as that's where you start. If you code for the latest features and **then** try to make it work for, say, IE7, you're in a world of pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're trying to use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), so first off let me say that your syntax that includes it is wrong. You have this.

```
<script src="http://nitrodatanetworks.com/assets/modernize.js.css"/>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and it should be this (Notice: Filename extension)

```
<script src="http://nitrodatanetworks.com/assets/modernize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How Modernizr works:

When your page is loaded, modernizr runs and detects what "features" are usable for the current browser, and will add special class names to the `html` tag of the page. For example I see you're using `CSS Gradients`, if you load the page on an outdated browser with no support for `CSS Gradients`, the html tag will look similar to this `<html class="no-cssgradients">`.

You can now specifiy rules that target when `CSS Gradients` are not supported.

Like this:
This will be your default class (obviously vender prefixes were left out)

```
    .exampleclass {
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4c4c4c 0%, #000000 0%, #000000 0%, #595959 12%, #666666 25%, #474747 39%, #2c2c2c 50%, #111111 60%, #2b2b2b 76%, #1c1c1c 91%, #131313 100%);
}
```

and for your fallback you can use the no-cssgradients class like this. So when no cssgradients are supported this class will apply to your element.

```
.no-cssgradients .exampleclass {
     background: #000000;
}
```

With the background property you can just provide the fallback inside the default tag, but I seperated it this way just as an example. The same process applies to other unsupported elements detected by Modernizr. There is more to modernizr than just classes so I'd recommend heading over to their site and start digging around.

Edit: I also recommend to run your html & CSS through a validator, you'll see that you have plenty of syntax errors throughout your code.  Nonethless good luck!

Comment: Should I download it or just copy/paste the code to my Javascript file/folder?

Comment: @ChrisEinarSanAgustin, it's really up to you. If you want to minimize the number of requests the client has to make to the server, keeping your javascript in one file is the way to go. If it doesn't really matter you can just download it and include it as it's own file.